# Silverlight toolkit Expander doesn't expand when the size of its content changes

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, expander

I have a silverlight expander control which wraps a grid. In the grid, I have a number of text boxes, combo boxes as well as some invisable (collapsed) text blocks. I also have an animation and when it is triggered the grid shows those hidden text blocks.

My problem is, when the hidden text blocks are shown after the animation is run, these text blocks push other controls down and because the expander doesn't resize itself, the controls at the bottom get pushed outside of the expander and become invisible.

I tried to call UpdateLayout() after the SizeChanged event of the grid but doesn't work.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be much appreciated!!

Comment: What is the row height ( *, auto, xxx px)?

Comment: it's auto. the height and width of the grid are all auto. the rows in the grid are all set to auto. the heights are based on the heigh of the controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually have fixed this problem by myself. I discovered in the style of the expander control, a while ago I put an ExpandableContentControl instead of normal ContentControl because it has a nice animation when you expand/collpase it. But this control doesn't resize properly... (see http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/4544?ProjectName=silverlight) I guess this is why the AccordionItem control is so buggy because it also has an ExpandableContentControl in it. As soon as I replaced the ExpandableContentControl with a normal ContentControl, the expander worked as expected. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problems is because the expander always use the same width (or height), so you must recalculate the width of the grid by code and assign it to the columndefinition.

Comment: Sorry but this is not the real problem. I have already given an answer as below. :)